# passing flask python variables on the server to reactjs as props

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

```
I'm trying to pass flask variables from the server to react but I can't get it working. At the moment I have a render function in a reactjs file that looks like:
ReactDOM.render(
  <Attribute prop1='{{ prop1 }}' prop2='{{ prop2 }}' />,
  document.getElementById('main')
);
```

In python on the flask server I have:

```
return render_template('index.html', prop1=var1, prop2=var2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
  <Attribute prop1={ prop1 } prop2={ prop2 } />
```