# Flask: passing Python variables on the server to React component

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I am practicing Flask + React in [this repo](https://github.com/CamiloGarciaLaRotta/fullstack_app_boilerplate).

I currently have the same issue,
I am unable to pass variables from Flask to React components through props.
I have found [this older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46139389/passing-flask-python-variables-on-the-server-to-reactjs-as-props) but it didn't provide more insight.

My code boils down to:

server.py

```
def index():
return render_template('index.html', bar='hello')
```

index.jsx

```
ReactDOM.render(<App foo={ bar } />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

Console Error

```
index.jsx?3769:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: bar is not defined
```

What is the appropriate way of passing information from the server to the components?

Thank you very much in advance

**UPDATE**

I figured out a solution, here are [the changes](https://github.com/CamiloGarciaLaRotta/fullstack_app_boilerplate/commit/5d58a81add72e0d6bed296c65445c6445798bc42).

Is that the "scotch-taped" way of passing data? or that is as good as it gets?

Comment: Can you push the branch that you are working on in github? It's hard to figure out how did you mount your component.

Comment: Yes of course, sorry. I had continued trying to solve the issue and modified the original code. Here is  [the branch](https://github.com/CamiloGarciaLaRotta/fullstack_app_boilerplate/tree/vars_as_props) with the exact setup that I asked about in this post

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are trying to access to template variable directly from your javascript code. you cannot have a direct access.

There is multiple ways to pass variables from your html template to your React DOM. Here are two options that you can use :

in your template index.html, the variable bar passed through attributes :

`<div id="content" data-foo={bar}></div>
<script>
  window.test = { bar }; // the variable bar passed in a script tag
</script>`

in your index.jsx:

`ReactDOM.render(
  <App{...(content.dataset)} test={test}/>,
  document.getElementById('content')
);`

Here is a jsfiddle with an example of code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/claudericka/stcvon58/1/)